# Transclude (?) infobox from Wikipedia to my own wiki

Tags: mediawiki

I am using MediaWiki to create a commonplace book. For the "author" pages I would like to include the infobox from that author's page on Wikipedia. Is there a routine, automated way to embed (transclude?) an infobox from Wikipedia on a page in my own MediaWiki installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as such. You can [enable scary transcluding](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEnableScaryTranscluding) but that will only let you transclude full pages (or maybe full sections when used with 
[Labeled Section Transclusion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Labeled_Section_Transclusion)). You can [generate the infobox from Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Infobox_Tutorial), but that's not always the same data you see on Wikipedia.